# Pre-populate dropdown list in a bootstrap modal w/ asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

How to pre-populate a dropdown list inside a bootstrap modal based on the link? 
Having in mind that the page wont load.

This is the link to fire the modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-interest">Open Modal</a>
```

Inside this modal I have a basic dropdown list like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem>Option 1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Option 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And I wanted to have the default option selected based on the link.
Is that possible having this structure?

Comment: Have you resolved this? Can you post your ASPX for your modal?

Comment: No, I didn't, sorry. I'm just using a "Select Option" as the default and making it a required field.